# Positionate div images without absolute

Tags: html, css, image

Okay I have a small problem,who I cant solve.
I hope experts will help :)

[image: index site]

As you can see I have 3 divs on my index site.
No in the middle is one input who is across header and main div.
And the yellow circles are divs with but images*

About the div images...their code is
The positions are random,not equal as I have done.
HTML and CSS

```css
#container{position:relative;}

.circle{border-radius:50%;
    width:127px;
    height:127px
    positionate:absolute;
}
#apple_img{
    background-image:url(../images/sprite.png);
    background-position: some pixels;
    top:-5px;
    left:15px;
}
#weight_img{
    background-image:url(../images/sprite.png);
    background-position: some pixels;
    top:30px;
    left:80px;
}
#bike_img{
    background-image:url(../images/sprite.png);
    background-position: some pixels;
    top:100px;
    left:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="apple_img" class="circle"></div>
    <div id="weight_img" class="circle"></div>
    <div id="bike_img" class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

So my problem is when re sizing the windows it will go as the div1,they will go across each other. I need too to make it responsible,but when using mobile,i need them to disapear, and when on smaller displays I need them to adjust their size to display.
Is the positioning okay or should I use `float`?

Comment: If you want to make the absolutely positioned divs even slightly responsive...don't use pixel values...use percentages. Then look into media queries.

Comment: Should it be better % or em-s?

Comment: I really wish you would explain what you need in a more elaborate manner. I have no idea what you are asking for.

Comment: The main problems are the circles who are divs...not the input...i need them to stay on the same position when display size changes...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very confusing but I guess that you want is something like this:

In can resize without problems using media queries.
Here is the link of mdn: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

You can also use `float:left` and `position:relative` for your divs and `position:absolute` for your input.

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
    .circle {
        
    }
    #apple_img {
        background:green;
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        float:left;
        position:relative;
    }
    #weight_img {
        background:red;
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        float:left;
        position:relative;
    }
    #bike_img {
        background:blue;
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        float:left;
        position:relative;
    }
    /* use media query here to other resolutions >768px and <=768px for example */
    div > input{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-100px;
        top:50px
    }
    
    input{
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
        <div id="apple_img" class="circle"></div>
        <div id="weight_img" class="circle"></div>
        <div id="bike_img" class="circle"></div>
        <div><input type="text" value="Type here"></div>
    </div>
```

I guess that your class "circle" is not doing what you want, then I commented it (try used it to check).

For the tags `div > input` and `input` you can use the media query to resize correctly your input.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dhvuakjr/

Ps.: It's position and not positionate like you wrote your class circle

Hope this help you.